# Modifying select with further check to exlclude values in separate table with a similar column name

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT count(res_c.id) FROM res_c WHERE id = '5552';
```

Counts 8 records. And works fine but needs a further check. My below attempt counts over a thousand - so isn't working right. I think it's because res_sear has an "ID" column too. How do I get around that? The below should count 8 like the above BUT checking and excluding records where res_sear.position = 'X'.

```
SELECT count(res_c.id)  
FROM res_c, res_sear
WHERE res_c.id = '5552'
AND res_sear.id NOT IN 
(SELECT res_sear.id FROM res_sear WHERE res_sear.position = 'X');
```

Do I need a join? What's the right way to do this?

Comment: This is one of the advantages of the ANSI 92 sysntax. we literally can't write a JOIN without specifying the ON condition

Comment: How are `res_c` and `res_sear` related? If it's by the `id` column in both tables, then the query doesn't make much sense; you want the `id` to be `'5552'` also the same `id` not to be in (subquery)? That can be written much more simply, with no need for `NOT IN` or any other join or anti-join. Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have `res_sear` in the `FROM` clause. Rather:

```
SELECT count(res_c.id)  
FROM res_c
WHERE res_c.id = '5552'
AND res_c.id NOT IN       --   res_c.id here, not res_sear.id !!
(SELECT res_sear.id FROM res_sear WHERE res_sear.position = 'X');
```

Comment: Garrrr. I swear I tried that and it didn't work! Can't beat a good pair of second eyes. Thank you all for your answers but this seems to have sorted it.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the join condition between res_c & res_sear in your outer query. Just add the the column on which the two tables can be joined and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `left join` like

```
SELECT count(res_c.id)  
FROM res_c
left join res_sear
on res_c.id = res_sear.id
and res_sear.position = 'X'
WHERE res_c.id = '5552'
AND res_sear.id is null;
```

(OR) just like below

```
SELECT count(res_c.id)  
FROM res_c JOIN res_sear
on res_c.id = res_sear.id
WHERE res_c.id = '5552'
AND res_sear.position <> 'X';
```